# How to display a widget inside a main window

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer, qmainwindow

I have a project *marines* with the following files structure:

- marines.pro
- FORMS

  - iran.ui
  - marines.h
- Headers

  - iran.h
  - marines.h
- Sources

  - iran.cpp
  - main.cpp
  - marines.cpp

I added the widget iran in the project marines.

Here is marines.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "marines.h"
#include "iran.h"


marines::marines(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::marines)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->actionExit, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(close()));
    connect(ui->actionIran, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(ir()));
}

void marines::ir()
{
//slot to display iran ui inside my main window
}

marines::~marines()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and here is my iran.cpp

```
#include "iran.h"
#include <QtGui>

iran::iran(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::iran)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

iran::~iran()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

How can I display the widget iran I made in Qt Designer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It all depends on how you want the widget to be displayed.

1. You could [add a layout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#setLayout) to your [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmainwindow.html#centralWidget) in your MainWindow and [add](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlayout.html#addWidget) your custom widget to the layout.
2. If you want your custom widget to be centralWidget of the MainWindow then use setCentralWidget.
3. If you want the custom widget as a subWindow then add MdiArea to your MainWindow. Then add custom widget to you MdiArea.
4. If you just want the custom widget to be displayed as a window, then just use `widget.show()`.

It's better to look at [Qt's examples to understand how a MainWindow is used.](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/examples-mainwindow.html)

Comment: if I may add, I believe option 4 would require *parent = 0  in the constructor (which means it is not a child of any other widgets and will be created as a window)

Answer (score 3):

```
marines::marines(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::marines)
{
    ui->setupUi(this); // after this
    iran *ir = new iran(); // create variable ir
    ir->show(); // show window
    ...
}
```